# Combining two fields into a single field with a space between

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have been trying to combine the first and last names into a single field with a space between example is John Doe.

When I do the following concat I get JohnDoe and not John Doe

```
SELECT     LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.gpEmployeeList.firstName)) AS [First Name], LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.gpEmployeeList.LASTNAME)) AS [Last Name], 
                      dbo.gpEmployeeList.SecurityCode AS [Security Code], dbo.gpEmployeeList.PTO AS [Available PTO], { fn CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.gpEmployeeList.firstName)), 
                      dbo.gpEmployeeList.LASTNAME) } AS DisplayName
FROM         dbo.MonthName INNER JOIN
                      dbo.gpEmployeeList ON dbo.MonthName.monthNumber = dbo.gpEmployeeList.BIRTHMONTH LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.domainAccounts ON dbo.gpEmployeeList.LASTNAME = dbo.domainAccounts.sn
```

Any suggestions for a fix?  I have to do the trim to get rid of a mess of spaces between the names.

Comment: Add a space in your `CONCAT` method. `concat(field, ' ', field2)`.

Comment: When I add the space I get CONCAT Function requires 2 arguments error.  I was hoping this would have worked earlier as well.

Comment: Not sure why, works for me here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc7c51/1

Comment: I am not sure why myself.  It's a head scratcher for sure on my end.

Comment: You don't have to use `concat()` -- `+` works the same.  `field + ' ' + field`

Comment: Have tried it both ways with out success.  I am wondering if it because I am pulling views from another DB and not working in the same DB

Comment: LTRIM(RTRIM(LASTNAME)) + ',' + LTRIM(RTRIM(firstName))  I changed the format and it works fine.  It must be the trim overriding the insert of a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONCAT is a SQL Sever 2012 function and does not exists in previous version.  If you run the sqlfiddle that sgeddes created, which is setup as MS SQL Sever 2012, the query runs. However, if you change it to MS SQL sever 2008 and rebuild the schema it throws an error. I assume you're not running 2012 because you're getting a concat error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Wrapping the function in brackets will make it work but I don't see the need.

SOCALNoob hit the nail on the head. The + will combine columns and text together quite nicely. I don't see why the below would not work.

```
 LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.gpEmployeeList.firstName)) + ' ' + dbo.gpEmployeeList.LASTNAME) AS DisplayName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either ones :

1- SELECT     LTRIM(RTRIM(firstName)) AS [First Name], LTRIM(RTRIM(lastName)) AS [Last Name], 
                   { fn CONCAT ({ fn CONCAT(firstName, ' ')}, lastName) } AS DisplayName
FROM         yourTable

OR

2- SELECT     LTRIM(RTRIM(firstName)) AS [First Name], LTRIM(RTRIM(lastName)) AS [Last Name], 
                   firstName +' ' + lastName AS DisplayName
FROM         yourTable